# How reorder a typed list using linq using the orderBy a string?

Tags: .net, linq, list, sorting, dynamic

I want to reorder this list using linq but the reordered list MUST be of the same type as the original list (no stupid "var =") and the "order by" is provided as **STRING** (not regular OrderBy type safe).

```
public class People{
public string Name { get; set; }
public int Age { get; set; }    }

List<People> lst = new List<People>();
People p = new People();
p.Name = "AAA";
p.Age = 10;
lst.Add(p);

p = new People();
p.Name = "XXX";
p.Age = 5;
lst.Add(p);

List<People> orderedListByAge = lst.SomeSort("Age");    
List<People> orderedListByName = lst.SomeSort("Name");
```

Comment: Do you not understand what `var` is? Also show what you've done so far. This is free not code-writing site. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: _(no stupid "var =")_ why are you so opposed against the idea of a short hand for the type? I dont care what datatype a linq query produces, but what it does. I mean, using .ToList() on every query is just not what linq's lazy nature was made for and it doesnt make reading your queries easier.

Comment: "var=" is stupid because 1)Remember me typeless code like horrible languages javascript and visual fox pro. 2)After the "var=" if you need to use the result set in a typed way, you need to cast. 3)In many cases the code is less readable. ex.: var=MyMethod(). You need to inspect the method's return value to understand what came. 4)Remind me pointers. I put a hard effort to avoid "var=" in my code. There are many ways to make coding easier. "var=" is not one of them, in my humble opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, i found this example [here](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library)

There is a zip with some examples. The class that solve my problem is "DynamicExample.cs". And the casting is done this way:

```
List<People> orderedByAge = (List<People>)DynamicExample.OrderBy(lst, "Age").Cast<People>().ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
        List<People> lst = new List<People> {
            new People { Name = "AAA", Age = 10},
            new People { Name = "XXX", Age = 5}
        };

        List<People> foo = lst.OrderBy(x => x.Age).ToList();
        List<People> bar = lst.OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList();
```

Comment: you need `ToList()`

Comment: lst.OrderBy(x => x.Age) <-- Where is the string "Age" i mentioned? This is the regular linc ordering system.